# Testing Smooth Scrolling with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, testing, scroll, jasmine

I'm using a JS Script to implement smooth scrolling.

I wonder is there any way to test this functionality with Jasmine?

Does it really worth testing?

This is the code I'm using:

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing animations is really tricky and I think layouts and animations shouldn't be tested in unit tests.
But you could try jasmine.Clock to simulate time. The doc is <s>[here](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/jsdoc/symbols/jasmine.Clock.html)</s>.

Update:

[Here](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.4/Clock.html) is an updated link to the clock docs